# Selecting only records where a certain data does not exist

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to come up with a query which excludes certain records that have a specific value.
Here's a snippet of my code:

```
CREATE TABLE #myMenu
    ([Id] int, [dish] varchar(100), [dishtype] varchar(10), [amount] int, [ingredient]     varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO #myMenu
    ([Id], [dish], [dishtype], [amount], [ingredient])
VALUES
    (1, 'salad', 'appetizer', 1, 'nuts'),
    (1, 'salad', 'appetizer', 1, 'lettuce'),
    (2, 'chicken cashew nuts', 'main', 2, 'chicken'),
    (2, 'chicken cashew nuts', 'main', 9, 'nuts'),
    (3, 'chicken marsala', 'main', 0, 'chicken'),
    (3, 'chicken marsala', 'main', 0, 'pepper'),
    (4, 'roast pork macadamia', 'main', 2, 'nuts'),
    (4, 'roast pork macadamia', 'main', 2, 'pork')  
;
```

Now what I want to do is to select all dishes that don't have nuts. Which should only have:

```
(3, 'chicken marsala', 'main'
```

Comment: How do you know if something has nuts? Is it just the ingredient table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select M.Id, M.Dish, M.DishType
  from #myMenu as M inner join
    ( select Id, Sum( case when Ingredient = 'nuts' then 1 end ) as Nutty from #MyMenu group by Id ) as Nuts
    on Nuts.Id = M.Id and Nuts.Nutty is NULL
  group by M.Id, M.dish, M.dishtype
```

or:

```
select distinct M.Id, M.Dish, M.DishType
  from #myMenu as M inner join
    ( select Id, Sum( case when Ingredient = 'nuts' then 1 end ) as Nutty from #MyMenu group by Id ) as Nuts
    on Nuts.Id = M.Id and Nuts.Nutty is NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

The code is below but the table you provided need to be normalized and split it into more that one table.

```
 select [Id],[dish],[dishtype]  
 from #myMenu  
 group by [Id],[dish],[dishtype]
 having sum(Case When ingredient='nuts' Then 1 Else 0 End)=0
```

Comment: The table I provided is an aggregation of multiple tables. It's a simplified form.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
FROM myMenu
WHERE ingredient != 'nuts' AND
dish NOT LIKE '%macadamia%' AND
dish NOT LIKE '%cashew%'
```

If you wanted to only include main dishes you can just add AND dishType = 'main'

Comment: You should get two rows.  That's because you have two rows that do not have nuts. Chicken Marsala with chicken and Chicken Marsala with peppers.  If you just want a single dish name, you can do SELECT DISTINCT dish instead of SELECT *.  This will only give you the name of the dish though.

Comment: Don't hardcode dish names into the query. Also, the correct results are in the question: `(3, 'chicken marsala', 'main'`